# In Docker, how do I copy files from a local directory so that I can then copy those files into my Docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, copy, dockerfile

I'm using Docker

```
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b
```

I have the following docker-compose.yml file ...

```
version: "3.2"
services:

  sql-server-db:
    build: ./
    container_name: sql-server-db
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "Password1!"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

and here is the Docker file it uses to build ...

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
  
# Create work directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/work

WORKDIR /usr/work

# Copy all scripts into working directory
COPY . /usr/work/

# Grant permissions for the import-data script to be executable
RUN chmod +x /usr/work/import-data.sh

EXPOSE 1433

CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

On my local machine, I have some files in a "../../scripts/myproject/*.sql" directory (the ".." are relative to the directory where my docker-compose.yml file is stored).  Is there a way I can run "docker-compose up" and have those files copied into a directory from which I can then copy them into the container's "/usr/work" directory?

Comment: Some things are a little unclear. Is it important to you that only `.sql` files are mounted and that other file types are ignored? Also, are you saying that the directory `../../scripts/myproject/*.sql` should be copied to another directory and only then be copied to your container or can the `../../scripts/myproject/*.sql` also be copied directly into the container?

Comment: To answer your first question, no, it is not important if all files types are mounted or only sql ones.  For your second question, it is fine if ../../scripts/myproject/*.sql is copied directly to the container.  I had been under the impression that only files in the same directory as Dockerfile could be copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to solve this, with one being easier than the other, but both have use cases.

**The easy way**

You could mount the directory directly to the container through the `docker-compose` like this:

```yaml
version: "3.2"
services:

  sql-server-db:
    build: ./
    container_name: sql-server-db
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "Password1!"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    volumes:
      - ../../scripts/myproject:/path/to/dir
```

Note the added `volumes` compared to the yaml in your question. This will mount the `myproject` directory to `/path/to/dir` within the container. What this will also mean is that if the `sql-server-db` container writes to any of the files in `/path/to/dir`, then the file in `myproject` on the host machine will also change, since the files are mounted.

**The less easy way**

You could copy the files directly during the build of the image. This is a little bit harder, since the build stage of docker doesn't allow the copying of parent directories unless you add some extra arguments. What needs to happen is that you set the `context` of the build stage to a different directory than the current directory. The `context` determines which files are sent to the build stage. This is the same directory as the directory the `Dockerfile` resides in by default.

To take this approach, you need the following in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.2"
services:

  sql-server-db:
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: path/to/Dockerfile # Here you should specify the path to your Dockerfile, this is a relative path from your context
    container_name: sql-server-db
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: "Password1!"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

So above the `context` is now `../..` so that you are able to copy files two directories above. You can then copy the `myproject` directory in your Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest

COPY ./scripts/myproject /myfiles
```

The advantage of this approach is that the files are copied instead of being mounted, so the docker container can write whatever it wants to these files, without affecting the host machine.

Comment: For your first solution, should I then be able to access "/path/to/dir" in Dockerfile?  I'm tryihng "COPY /path/to/dir/* /usr/work/" but am getting the error "ERROR: Service 'sql-server-db' failed to build: COPY failed: no source files were specified".

Comment: Yes, the `COPY` step is not necessary anymore in your Dockerfile.

Comment: Correction*, you don't have to access the directory in your Dockerfile anymore. The directory will be mounted at runtime when the container starts, before mssql initializes if that's important to you.